# Typescript 2 frozen object of any shape behavior

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Suppose I deal with some object, inner structure of which is unknown as I didn't create it. For example I got reference to object `attributes` containing html attributes, then I made shallow copy and freezed it with Object.freeze({...attributes}).

I tried to describe shape like

```
interface HTMLAttributes = Readonly<{
  [attribute: string]: string
}>

or like

interface HTMLAttributes = {
  readonly [attribute: string]: string
}
```

but I still cannot achieve expected error on direct assignment `attributes.class = '<stuff>'`

Assignment by `attributes['class'] = '<stuff>'` throws as expected.

Example ([view it on the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Example%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20readonly%20%5Battribute%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20x%3A%20Example%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ax%5B%27test%27%5D%20%3D%20%27foo%27%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Permits%20only%20reading%0D%0A%0D%0Ax.test%20%3D%20%27foo%27%3B%20%2F%2F%20No%20Error%0D%0A)):

```
interface Example {
  readonly [attribute: string]: string
}

var x: Example = {};

x['test'] = 'foo'; // Error: Permits only reading

x.test = 'foo'; // No Error
```

Comment: You should not be able to use direct assignment like `attributes.class = '<stuff>'` at all. Unless you cast your object to `any` - tsc will complain. And if you cast it to any - then of course all checks are gone.

Comment: Yes, but I am) I still cannot understand, why typechecking triggers for my string index signature and doesn't work in <dot>property case. Is it necessary to enable some options in tsconfig? I spent a lot of time trying to find explanation, reading docs and issues, but still lack of convenient answer (

Comment: I have added reasoning behind as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is described by the following portion of the typescript [specs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#394-index-signatures):

> Index signatures affect the determination of the type that results from applying a bracket notation property access to an instance of the containing type, as described in section 4.13.

In other words your restriction will be applied only while bracket notation is used.

Comment: Understood) Thank you!